# Swift + Xcode - Share current location

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, text, location

I am attempting to simulate the process of going to a contact -> clicking share location -> selecting amount of time to share for all through code. I was wondering if this is possible and what the process is? I already have a system set up to get the current location and send the latitude and longitude in a Google Maps link through SMS, but I am looking for more of a real-time update on someones location. Thanks!